# Delete abbreviations (combination of Letter+dot) from Pandas column

Tags: pandas, string, replace

I'd like to delete specific parts of strings in a pandas column, such as any letter followed by a dot. For example, having a column with names:

```
John W. Man
Betty J. Rule
C.S. Stuart
```

What should remain is

```
John Man
Betty Rule
Stuart
```

SO, any letter followed by a dot, that represents an abbreviation, should go.
I can't think of a way with str.replace or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with reegx for match one letter with `.` and space after it if exist:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('([a-zA-Z]{1}\.\s*)','', regex=True)
print (df)
          col
0    John Man
1  Betty Rule
2      Stuart
```